# input validation vs. required to submit on multi-page forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate

i have a multi-page form that i am trying to validate using jquery validate. the user has essentially 4 options: `next`, `prev`, `save`, `submit`.

`save`, `next`, and `prev` all save the current page to the form as a whole; `submit` is the same as `save`, but fires some additional workflow-related functions then heads off to another part of the site.

i need to validate the user input at all times. the jquery validate is working great. but... i need to have some fields set as required. because the form is saved at each step, the input needs to always be valid, but i don't need the required validation until the very end (on `submit`).

the form is building a dynamic list of validations specific to the page it is on, like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ctl01").validate({ onsubmit: false });
    $("#_Qn_0e868ebe").rules("add", { maxlength: 200 });
    $("#_Qn_d69e75a4").rules("add", { number: true });
    $("#_Qn_adffbdec").rules("add", { maxlength: 200 });
    $("#_Qn_adffbdec").rules("add", { digits: true });
});
```

so now, for required fields, i've added a `.isrequired` class to them, and i've decoupled the `<asp:linkbutton>`s to fire this client script:

```
function FormIsValid(sender, ishardsubmit) {
    var form = $("#ctl01");
    form.validate();
    if (form.valid()) {
        //if (ishardsubmit) {
        //    if (!IsRequiredValid()) { return false; }
        //}
        __doPostBack(sender, '');
    }
    return;
}
```

this part (the input validation part) is working great so far. the part i commented out is the part that is working not so great. it fires this function, in which i was trying to dynamically add required validators and re-evaluate the form. i can see it hit the .each loop for each of my required fields, but it doesn't seem to be working since it passes `true` back, even when required fields are empty.

```
function IsRequiredValid() {
    var $requiredgroup = $(".isrequired");
    $requiredgroup.each(function (i, item) {
        $(item).rules("add", { required: true });
    });
    form.validate();
    return form.valid();
}
```

i toyed with the idea of dropping the .net required field validators in to do this part, but i want to, if possible, stick with a single solution. especially since this feels *so* close to working.

thoughts? help? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jQuery `.each()` method is constructed improperly.

You want to target the whole object in your iteration, not key/value pairs.  So remove `i, item` from the function arguments and use `$(this)` as the target selector.

```
function IsRequiredValid() {
    var $requiredgroup = $(".isrequired");
    $requiredgroup.each(function() {
        $(this).rules("add", { required: true });
    });
    // form.validate(); // remove this line -> 100% superfluous
    return form.valid();
}
```

---

Regarding your `form.validate()` line in both functions: You cannot call `.validate()` more than once on the page. It's only meant to be called *once* to initialize the plugin on your form.

Calling it subsequent times will have no effect. Otherwise, we wouldn't need to use the `.rules()` method as we would simply call `.validate()` any time we need to change rules. However, this is definitely not the case.

Comment: yes! i had to add another function in to unset the required (in case you decided to save or page-change instead of submit after fixing the input): `$(this).rules("remove", "required");` 

working perfect, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Add a class to your required fields called something like: "SubmitRequired"
Implement two functions as follows:

```
function SaveClick(){
//ignore SubmitRequired on save (and any disabled fields)
  $("form").validate({ ignore: ".SubmitRequired, [disabled]" });  

  if $("form").valid()
  {
    do something;
  }
}

function SubmitClick(){
//ignore only disabled fields (if any))
  $("form").validate({ ignore: "[disabled]" });  

  if $("form").valid()
  {
    do something;
  }
}
```

Comment: nice, i missed the `ignore`. however, won't this also disable type|format validation on a field that is, say, both required and must-be-a-number?

Comment: @will_, This answer will not work.  You cannot just call `.validate()` any time you want to change an option.  The `.validate()` method can only be called **once** to _initialize_ the plugin and any subsequent call is ignored.